# Renaming of JAX-WS Project - Now can't find WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I had a perfectly working server side web service application up and running - which my friend was able to connect to with a particular url ending in `?wsdl` This morning we had the great idea of renaming our application using a find and replace and also moving it to a different box (in a different location)

This has essentially turned out to be a disaster and we can no longer figure out what path the iOS app should use to connect to my web service.

Is there a way I can regenerate a wsdl file of some sorts or something along these lines in order to be able to tell him the path to the service.

I have seen some comments suggesting the path should be as follows;

```
http://<hostname>:<port>/<webappname>/<servletEndpoint>?wsdl
```

Assuming my end point - as defined in the sun-jaxws.xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
  <endpoint
     name="vimbaserver"
     implementation="com.vimba.service.ExposedFunctions"
     url-pattern="/messages"/>
</endpoints>
```

Would this mean that the full wsdl path would be

```
http://boxipaddress:80/<deployed-war-file-name>/vimbaserver?wsdl
```

Or is there a process for generating this value?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in your question, the URL should look like this:

```
http://vimbaserver:80/messages?wsdl
```

The `url-pattern` attribute specifies the servlet endpoint. The exception to this would be if your web service application has a context root that needs to be specified in the url, in which case it would be:

```
http://vimbaserver:80/contextroot/messages?wsdl
```

Comment: hi - thanks for the reply - i just made an edit to my post - would it require the box ip address the war file is running on?

Comment: Yes, it would require the box ip address and, if configured, the context root.

Comment: i am getting file not found error when i try this `http://90.214.64.170:80/vimbaserver/messages?wsdl`